# Sorting Arraylist in a custom order

Tags: java, sorting

Thank you for lending your time :)

I have a piece of code that sorts Arraylist using compareToIgnoreCase.

```
Collections.sort(als,new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            //I want to alter this part
            int dif=o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2); 
            return dif;
        }


    });
```

But I want to sort the arraylist in the following manner:

input:  (in any order)

```
sherin
Sherin
SHERIN
bubBle
buBble
BUBBLE
heart
hEart
hEArt
```

output :

```
BUBBLE
buBble
bubBle
hEArt
hEart
heart
SHERIN
Sherin
sherin
```

Could you please help me with this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you need to create a Comparator and pass it to the Collections.sort(list,comparator). Since, your sorting order is case sensitive, you shoudl not be using compareToIgnoreCase(o2)

Comment: I need help with the logic I have to use in Comparator.

Comment: What rule specifies the collation order?  Is it AaBbCcDd... etc?  You will need a custom comparator to accomplish this.

Comment: @JimGarrison sorting should be in alphabetical order. But when it comes to 'a,A' A should come first. I don't know what a collation order is. AaBbCcDd... I guess.

Comment: your aim is to sort based the Upper case Character in the String?

Comment: sort on the basis of ASCII code of the string characters.

Comment: A Collation Order is a list of all the characters in the order you want them sorted.  Since you are re-ordering the alphabetics you'll have to decide where all the other code points go in relation to them, otherwise when someone gives you a string containing a character you haven't handles you can get one of several different exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int n1 = s1.length();
        int n2 = s2.length();
        int min = Math.min(n1, n2);
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
            char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            char l1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1);
            char l2 = Character.toLowerCase(c2);

            if (u1 != u2) {
                return u1 - u2;
            } else {
                if (l1 != l2) {
                    return l1 - l2;
                } else if (c1 != c2) {
                    return c1 - c2;
                }
            }
        }
        return n1 - n2;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Your first try wasn't too bad, but you need to add another comparison in case of similar case insensitive values to order them :

```
Stream.of("sherin", "Sherin", "SHERIN", "bubBle", "buBble", "BUBBLE", "heart", "hEart", "hEArt")
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
        int tmp = s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2); 
        return tmp == 0 ? 
            s1.compareTo(s2) //Compare equivalent values based on the case (upper case first)
            : tmp;
    }).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The comparator provided to `Stream.sorted` is the same has your implementation but using a lambda notation.

Result :

```
BUBBLE
buBble
bubBle
hEArt
hEart
heart
SHERIN
Sherin
sherin
```

EDIT: Thanks to [*Joop Eggen*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) for the suggestion of using the comparator decorator :

```
Comparator
    .comparing(Function.identity(), String::compareToIgnoreCase)
    .thenComparing(Function.identity(), String::compareTo);
```

This is a bit cleaner to use and give the same result :

```
Stream.of("sherin", "Sherin", "SHERIN", "bubBle", "buBble", "BUBBLE", "heart", "hEart", "hEArt").sorted(
        Comparator
            .comparing(Function.identity(), String::compareToIgnoreCase)
            .thenComparing(Function.identity(), String::compareTo)
    ).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And the shorter I could do with this notation is :

```
Comparator.comparing((String s) ->.toLowerCase()).thenComparing(Function.identity())
```

Comment: Minus: `-s1.compareTo(s2)` and then the answer is just what the OP wanted: `b < B`

Comment: Not from the output I see in the question @JoopEggen : "_BUBBLE <
buBble_"

Comment: you are right - still did not have my morning coffee. BTW: nice occasion to offer comparing+andThen.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature @JoopEggen but this is added and this is indeed really nice.

Comment: You can even use the overloaded version, removing `Function.identity(),`.

Comment: I tried @JoopEggen but the method `comparing(Function, Comparator)` used is overloaded only with `comparing(Function)`. So I can't make this work with `comparing(String::compareToIgnoreCase)`.  But I can remove the second comparator since this is the defaut comparator for `String` and have `.thenComparing(Function.identity())`